# Remove vertical space below equations in 2 columns and single numbering for both equations in a column

Tags: spacing, equations, numbering

I had previously asked a question regarding vertical spacing between equations which are in two columns. This was answered but when I use the following code I get a large vertical space between these equations and the text below.

Further, currently, each of these equations gets an individual number. I want for both equations, i.e. the line of equations to have just one number. Therefore, ideally, the whole line should be numbered (8).

Can someone please help me with this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\begin{equation}
C_{O,t}(j) = (1-\alpha_c)\left(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\right)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)
\end{equation}\columnbreak
\begin{equation}
C_{Z,t}(j) = \alpha_c\left(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\right)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j).
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\noindent
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI), $P_{C,t}$ is given by,
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply using *one* `equation` instead of `multicols` and two `equation`s? Something like `$P_{O,t}$ are the core consumption deflator and the price of oil, respectively. This implies,
\begin{equation}
C_{O,t}(j) = (1-\alpha_c)\left(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\right)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)\qquad
C_{Z,t}(j) = \alpha_c\left(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\right)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j). 
\end{equation}
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI), $P_{C,t}$ is given by,`

Answer (score 1):

Given the desired output, I think that using `multicols` and two `equation` environments is not the right tool for the job at hand. You can either use just *one* `equation` adding some horizontal spacing or some other of the `amsmath`'s environments if multi-row alignment is desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$P_{O,t}$ are the core consumption deflator and the price of oil, respectively. This implies,
\begin{equation}
C_{O,t}(j) = (1-\alpha_c)\biggl(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\biggr)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)\qquad
C_{Z,t}(j) = \alpha_c\biggl(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\biggr)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j). 
\end{equation}
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI), $P_{C,t}$ is given by,

$P_{O,t}$ are the core consumption deflator and the price of oil, respectively. This implies,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
C_{O,t}(j) &= (1-\alpha_c)\biggl(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\biggr)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)\\
C_{Z,t}(j) &= \alpha_c\biggl(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\biggr)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j). 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI), $P_{C,t}$ is given by,

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I also changed the `\left`, `\right` pairs to `\bbigl`, `\bbigr` to avoid unnecessary horizontal spacing added for the former.

Answer (score 1):

You could use side-by-side `minipage` environments, each `0.5\textwidth` wide. Use an `equation*` environment in the first, and an `equation` environment in the second.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{7} % just for this example
\noindent 
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI), $P_{C,t}$ is given by \dots
\par\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation*}
C_{O,t}(j) = (1-\alpha_c)\left(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\right)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
C_{Z,t}(j) = \alpha_c\left(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\right)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j).
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\par\noindent
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI), $P_{C,t}$ is given by \dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for using a "two-column layout" here. Instead, use a single `equation` with either a fixed space between (something like `\qquad`) or one of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align`-like environments to spread out the equations evenly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\begin{document}

$P_{O,t}$ are the core consumption deflator and the price of oil, respectively. This implies
\begin{equation}
  C_{O,t}(j) = (1-\alpha_c)\mleft(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\mright)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)
  \qquad
  C_{Z,t}(j) = \alpha_c\mleft(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\mright)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j).
\end{equation}
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI),~$P_{C,t}$ is given by, \ldots

\noindent\hrulefill

$P_{O,t}$ are the core consumption deflator and the price of oil, respectively. This implies
\begin{align}
  C_{O,t}(j) = (1-\alpha_c)\mleft(\frac{P_{O,t}}{P_{C,t}}\mright)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j)
  &&
  C_{Z,t}(j) = \alpha_c\mleft(\frac{P_{Z,t}}{P_{C,t}}\mright)^{-\omega_c} C_{t}(j).
\end{align}
Therefore, the consumption-based price index (CPI),~$P_{C,t}$ is given by, \ldots

\end{document}
```